# Parse HTML in AngularJS ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

How do I parse HTML coming from the server via a string? 
I have this from the server:

```
<img src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/9a52267d32ad2aaa4a8c2c45b83396e5?d=mm&amp;s=&amp;r=G" class=" user-1-avatar avatar- photo" width="" height="" alt="Avatar Image" />
```

which comes in via a object property like:

```
{admin: {avatar "<img src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/9a52267d32ad2aaa4a8c2c45b83396e5?d=mm&amp;s=&amp;r=G" class=" user-1-avatar avatar- photo" width="" height="" alt="Avatar Image" />"}}
```

I've tried using ng-bind-html but no luck...
What can I use?

Comment: use $compile service of angularjs.

Comment: do you have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

later versions of AngularJS:

```
function HomeCtrl($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.object = {
  admin: {
    avatar : '<img src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/9a52267d32ad2aaa4a8c2c45b83396e5?d=mm&amp;s=&amp;r=G" class=" user-1-avatar avatar- photo" width="" height="" alt="Avatar Image" />'
},
fred: {
    avatar : '<img src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/9a52267d32ad2aaa4a8c2c45b83396e5?d=mm&amp;s=&amp;r=G" class=" user-1-avatar avatar- photo" width="" height="" alt="Avatar Image" />'
}};
  $scope.avatar = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.object.admin.avatar);
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div ng-bind-html="avatar"></div>
```

Working Demo : http://jsbin.com/butuwu/1/edit

Older version :

HTML:

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="avatar"></div>
```

JS:

```
function HomeCtrl($scope) {
  var object = {
  admin: {
    avatar : '<img src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/9a52267d32ad2aaa4a8c2c45b83396e5?d=mm&amp;s=&amp;r=G" class=" user-1-avatar avatar- photo" width="" height="" alt="Avatar Image" />'
}};
  $scope.avatar = object.admin.avatar;
}
```

Comment: the problem with this is that it doesn't work when using a modern version of angularJS http://jsbin.com/rikiyukaloza/1/edit

Comment: Updated your jsbin.. check the answer above :)

Comment: yeah my problem with that is that it comes in via the server and the value of "admin" is not always the same

Comment: In that case, you will be fetching object inside the service.. Then inject it inside the controller.. Just for demo purpose i have stubbed the object inside controller itself.

Comment: ended up using:
    app.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
        return function(val) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
        };
    });